# JsonDeserializer check before try to convert Model

Tags: c#

Read simple api call code bellow. Here i am getting call response in- `IRestResponse response` and its a json response. Then using `JsonDeserializer()` i am trying to convert it to a C# Model which is `WallMartData` model. ( i think i dont need to share model code here bcoz it doesn't matter for this question ). Now from this same response sometime i will get a json response which match with my model `WallMartData` and some time it will return other json response. Now my question is- before i try to convert my json response to `WallMartData` Model i want to check if this is a valid convertable json. If its not valid convartable for this `WallMartData` model then it will skip try to convert. Bcoz when its fails to convert i am getting invalid json exception on c#. Thats why i need to check before try to convert. Any solution?

```
string url = "http://api.example.com/v1/items?apiKey=" + Token + "&upc=" + UPC;
var client = new RestClient(url);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);


var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
var wmr = deserializer.Deserialize<WallMartData>(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a method use `try .... catch` to check the JSON string is or isn't valid.

```
private static bool IsValidJson<T>(string strInput,out T obj)
{
    obj = default(T);
    try
    {
        obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(strInput);
        return true;
    }
    catch (JsonReaderException jex)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can use `bool` to check the `DeserializeObject` whether success.

```
WallMartData wmr;
if(IsValidJson<WallMartData>(response,out wmr)){
    //... your logic with wmr
}
```

Comment: It can be valid but does not match WallMartData model and then throw Exception

Comment: bad answer, exceptions are usually a relatively expensive operation. So, exceptions should normally be used for exceptional events, not normal flow control

Comment: @styx Do you have another better answer I am looking forward to seeing:)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use try catch block and it will be enough. But if you really need to validate your JSON, you can use [JSON Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm). You can generate schema for your class using [JsonSchemaGenerator](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_JsonSchemaGenerator.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `JsonSchema` by `Json.Net`
more info [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm)

let's say that your `WallMartData` class looks like this

```
  public class WallMartData
    {        
        [JsonProperty("email", Required = Required.Always)]
        public string Email;

        [JsonProperty("first_name")]
        public string firstName;

        [JsonProperty("last_name")]
        public string lastName;


    }
```

Then you can easily use the schema checker

```
 JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
 JSchema schema = generator.Generate(typeof(WallMartData));

 string json = @"...";
 JObject wallMartData = JObject.Parse(json);
 if(wallMartData.IsValid(schema))
 {
        //if json matching the schema aka the class account
 }
 else
 {
     //the json is invalid
 }
```